# Changing the size & position of a childViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I followed this YouTube tutorial on creating a Navigation Controller for switching between multiple View Controllers with a Segmented Control: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kq-lHR5ZOW0

From here, I'd like to alter the size & position for the Segmented Control and the View Controllers inside the Navigation Controller.  Currently, the Views are being displayed underneath the Segmented Control and the Segmented Control is begin displayed under the status bar, such that everything is on top of each other at the top of the device.

[image]

How would I position the Segmented Control to sit lower than the status bar, and the View Controllers to sit lower than the Segmented Controls to prevent overlapping?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `UISegmentedControl` in the navigation bar and you need to add a "prompt" to the navigation bar to increase the height of the bar and add the prompt text above the content area of the bar.
By this way you can position the Segmented Control to sit lower than the status bar.And use another view to sit lower than the Segmented Controls to prevent overlapping.

This can be done purely in Interface Builder or programmatically using the following code:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationItem setPrompt:@"some prompt text"];
```